# Can I use models from Mobx-state-tree in shared code for validation on backend?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

I know that Mobx-state-tree mentions [tcomb](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb) as an influence - is it possible to have mobx-state-tree models shared between the front end and backend, so that I can perform validation checks using [tcomb-validation](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-validation) or should I just use the models and try to apply snapshot and surface those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your MST models are in pure JS, you can use them in any JS runtime: browser, node, RN, etc.